# Getting an error called "Instance deployment failed to install application dependencies." while deploying my project using aws elasticbean

Tags: deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-code-deploy

(ecom) C:\Users\HP\projects\ecom_project\skart>eb deploy
Creating application version archive "app-210329_112830".

Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
2021-03-29 05:59:36    INFO    Environment update is starting.
2021-03-29 06:00:16    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).

2021-03-29 06:00:24    ERROR :  Instance deployment failed to install application dependencies. The deployment failed.

2021-03-29 06:00:24    ERROR  : Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2021-03-29 06:00:26    ERROR  : [Instance: i-070c871305f5065c6] Command failed on
instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..

2021-03-29 06:00:26    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].

2021-03-29 06:00:26    ERROR :  Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-070c871305f5065c6'. Aborting the operation.
2021-03-29 06:00:27    ERROR   :Failed to deploy application.

ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.

Comment: Have you checked `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log` for details of the errors?

Comment: @Marcin No id did not, can you explain me what does it actually mean , i'm still a beginer in this.

Comment: try typing `eb logs` in your terminal to view the logs and share the outputs